# Create a pyspark Dataframe from a row in another Dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I have this Dataframe:

```
df_json = spark.sql(select id, type, json from process.base_json where)
df_json.show()

+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id    |  type  |                               json                                              |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|23016494|TAX     |{"Id":"253","RESULT":{"DATA":{"response":[{"message":"ID 253 invalid"}]}}}       |
|23020867|WARRANTY|{"Id":"108","RESULT":{"DATA":{"result":[{"message":"Nomatches"}]}},"Type":"ID"}  |
|23021055|WARRANTY|{"Id":"332","RESULT":{"DATA":{"detail":{"cre":"BANK","nid":"332"}]}},"Type":"ID"}|
|23016497|TAX     |{"Id":"643","RESULT":{"DATA":{"registry":[{"dv":"5","st":"ACT","name":"MAY"}]}}} |
+-----------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want for each row of the dataframe, to create a new dataframes to be able to parse the json individually.

```
df_json1
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id    |  type  |                               json                                              |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|23016494|TAX     |{"Id":"253","RESULT":{"DATA":{"response":[{"message":"ID 253 invalid"}]}}}       |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df_json2
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id    |  type  |                               json                                              |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|23020867|WARRANTY|{"Id":"108","RESULT":{"DATA":{"result":[{"message":"Nomatches"}]}},"Type":"ID"}  |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df_json3
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id    |  type  |                               json                                              |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|23021055|WARRANTY|{"Id":"332","RESULT":{"DATA":{"detail":{"cre":"BANK","nid":"332"}]}},"Type":"ID"}|
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df_json4
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id    |  type  |                               json                                              |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|23016497|TAX     |{"Id":"643","RESULT":{"DATA":{"registry":[{"dv":"5","st":"ACT","name":"MAY"}]}}} |
+-----------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on the purpose behind creating separate dataframes? It would be helpful to understand your ultimate objective

Comment: Can a single Dataframe with RESULT as a struct column be useful? or just converting this dataframe by adding columns RESULT (struct) and id extracted from the JSON?

Comment: The goal is to be able to dynamically infer the different schemas of the json in the dataframe, flatten them and transpose them into a value field structure (id, type, field, value). I already have built the functions that infer the schema, flatten the jason and transpose it, but everything is based on the input of a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_dict = {}

for i, row in enumerate(df_json.collect()):
    df_dict[f"df_json_{i+1}"] = spark.createDataFrame([row])

for df_keys in df_dict:
    df_dict[df_keys].show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id    |  type  |                               json                                              |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|23016494|TAX     |{"Id":"253","RESULT":{"DATA":{"response":[{"message":"ID 253 invalid"}]}}}       |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df_json2
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id    |  type  |                               json                                              |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|23020867|WARRANTY|{"Id":"108","RESULT":{"DATA":{"result":[{"message":"Nomatches"}]}},"Type":"ID"}  |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id    |  type  |                               json                                              |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|23021055|WARRANTY|{"Id":"332","RESULT":{"DATA":{"detail":{"cre":"BANK","nid":"332"}]}},"Type":"ID"}|
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id    |  type  |                               json                                              |
+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|23016497|TAX     |{"Id":"643","RESULT":{"DATA":{"registry":[{"dv":"5","st":"ACT","name":"MAY"}]}}} |
+-----------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```